# Zooming and Image filling the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, transform

I have an Image control class that zooms in/out, fills the screen, and does a 1:1 ratio (all controlled by 4 different buttons. However, when the screen resolution is bigger than 1280 x 1024, my fill screen and 1:1 ratio don't do what they are supposed to.

```
public void ZoomActual()
    {
        m_translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, CreateAnimation(0));
        m_translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, CreateAnimation(0));
        m_zoomFactor.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, CreateAnimation(1));
        m_zoomFactor.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, CreateAnimation(1));
    } //1:1 ratio button control

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is used to fill the screen with the current picture on the zoomandpan Control
    /// </summary>
    public void ZoomFit()
    {
        double screen_height = ActualHeight;
        double screen_width = ActualWidth;

        double image_width = m_source_child.ActualWidth;
        double image_height = m_source_child.ActualHeight;

        double image_ratio = image_width / image_height;
        double screen_ratio = screen_width / screen_height;

        if (image_width > image_height)
        {
            m_translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, CreateAnimation(0));
            m_translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, CreateAnimation(0));
            m_zoomFactor.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, CreateAnimation(1 / screen_ratio * image_ratio)); //width
            m_zoomFactor.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, CreateAnimation(1 / screen_ratio * image_ratio)); //height
        }
        else
        {
            m_translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, CreateAnimation(0));
            m_translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, CreateAnimation(0));
            m_zoomFactor.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, CreateAnimation((screen_ratio * image_ratio))); //width
            m_zoomFactor.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, CreateAnimation((screen_ratio * image_ratio))); //height
        }
    } //fillscreen button control

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is used to control the animations of the ZoomandPan. Animations consist of Zooming in
    /// and out of a picture and allows panning of the displayed image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a_toValue">used for zoom in percentage [currently set at: 1.5 (150%)]</param>
    /// <returns>Animation values image</returns>
    private DoubleAnimation CreateAnimation(double a_toValue)
    {
        var dubAni = new DoubleAnimation(a_toValue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)))
        {
            AccelerationRatio = 0.1,
            DecelerationRatio = 0.9,
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd
        };
        dubAni.Freeze();
        return dubAni;
    } //Animation value setter

    /// <summary>
    /// DoZoom is used for executing the physical zoom of the picture, enlarges or shrinks image depending
    /// on CreateAnimation values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a_deltaZoom">Determinded to be + or -. can be set by mousewheel and/or buttons. Determines Zoom in/out</param>
    /// <param name="a_mousePosition">Current positon of mouse</param>
    /// <param name="a_physicalPositon">refrence to last area mousePosition was on image</param>
    private void DoZoom(Double a_deltaZoom, Point a_mousePosition, Point a_physicalPositon)
    {
        double currentZoom = m_zoomFactor.ScaleX;
        currentZoom *= a_deltaZoom;
        if (currentZoom < MinZoom)
            currentZoom = MinZoom;
        else if (currentZoom > MaxZoom)
            currentZoom = MaxZoom;

        m_translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, CreateAnimation(-1 * (a_mousePosition.X * currentZoom - a_physicalPositon.X)));
        m_translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, CreateAnimation(-1 * (a_mousePosition.Y * currentZoom - a_physicalPositon.Y)));

        m_zoomFactor.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, CreateAnimation(currentZoom));
        m_zoomFactor.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, CreateAnimation(currentZoom));
    } //Zoom animation
```

When I way it doesn't do what it supposed to i mean this: If my screen has a resolution of 1280 x 1024 or lower, the fill screen will fill the screen and 1:1 ratio will give an actual size of the picture. any resolution that is bigger than 1280 x 1024 will cause the fill screen control to make the image smaller (inside the canvas) rather than putting the entire image on the window. And the 1:1 ratio control will have a small gap off to the right that is just white space. Any help offered is greatly appreciated, I'm kinda new to image control so this may seem pretty trivial. sorry bout that

Comment: What does your XAML look like? The `Image` control does its own fitting based on how much space it's given and the `Stretch` property.

Comment: <local:ZoomAndPan Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
                                  x:Name="zoomViewer"
                                  MinZoom="0.25" MaxZoom="4" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Height ="Auto" Width="Auto">
                        <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="Fill" />
                    </Canvas>
                </local:ZoomAndPan>

Comment: And what are the m_zoomFactor and m_translateTransform storyboards attached to? Please give everything needed to understand the code.

Comment: private void Setup()
        {
            m_source = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0) as Canvas;            //Visual tree as framework
            m_source = (Canvas)Content;
            m_source_child = (Image)m_source.Children[0];

Comment: m_translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
            m_zoomFactor = new ScaleTransform();
            m_transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
            m_transformGroup.Children.Add(m_zoomFactor); //enables zooming to be part of the transform group when modifying picture
            m_transformGroup.Children.Add(m_translateTransform);
            m_source.RenderTransform = m_transformGroup; //allows general modification of picture, in this case - zoom and pan
            Focusable = true;}

Comment: In the future you can edit your question with the extra code; it doesn't format very well in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you that in your **ZoomFit** function that you want to fill while maintaining the proper aspect ratio.  This is how I normally do that:

```
double ratio = Math.Min(destArea.Width / imageSize.Width, destArea.Height / imageSize.Height);

double imageWidth = imageSize.Width * ratio;
double imageHeight = imageSize.Height * ratio;
```

You should be able to supply the ratio directly to the ScaleTransform.

If you want to zoom to fill and maintain aspect ratio but trim the excess, you would simply use Math.Max to calculate the ratio instead of Math.Min.

Answer (score 0):

I think your basic problem is you've got some wonky math to work out the scaling factors in `ZoomFit`. For example, if your screen aspect ratio was 1:1, you would always zoom by a factor equal to the image aspect ratio. That means that a 2:1 image would always get zoomed in by 200%, no matter how big it actually is.